# How can I restore the default toolbar or add apps from the command line?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, linux

So I was messing around with the toolbar and ended up deleting the whole panel.  When I rebooted my Pi, the panel came back, but it was empty, so I opened the toolbar editor, and was able to add an application launch bar.  However, within the application launch bar editor, every time I try to add an app, the editor crashes, and my toolbar disappears (making me have to reboot).  Is there some other way to add apps to the toolbar without the editor, maybe through the command line? Is there some way to get the default toolbar back?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

***Question***

> However, within the application launch bar editor, every time I try to
>   add an app, the editor crashes, and my toolbar disappears (making me
>   have to reboot).

***Answer***

> Perhaps you forgot to ***tick the task bar in the panel apps menu before
>   closing***. (See the highlighted option in the picture below)

*I did find the menu design a bit confusing.  I once messed up everything and had to install a new SD card image! :)*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may try to purge (i.e. remove the package and the config files) and then reinstall `lxpanel`:

```
sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends lxpanel
sudp apt install lxpanel
```

Note that if you purge `lxpanel` using `apt`, it will uninstall all packages that depend on it, and they will not be automatically reinstalled once you install `lxpanel` again.